# CS0122: 'AmazonGlacierClient.ListVaults()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier, aws-sdk-net

I am getting the following error:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0122

> Program.cs(42,34): error CS0122: 'AmazonGlacierClient.ListVaults()' is inaccessible due to its protection level [/app/myglacier.csproj]

when running this code:

```
var response = this.client.ListVaults();
```

sdk links:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Glacier/MGlacierListVaults.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Glacier/TGlacierClient.html
3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/

#### My question:

**Why am I getting this error on a "virtual public" method?  Why isn't it accessible to me?**

Full Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Amazon.Glacier;
using Amazon.Glacier.Model;

namespace myglacier
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      Myglacier mg = new Myglacier();

      mg.init();

      var vl = mg.getVaults();
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
  }

  public class Myglacier
  {
    public AmazonGlacierClient client = null;
    public void init()
    {
        AmazonGlacierClient client;
        client = new AmazonGlacierClient("&&&&&&&&&", "++++++++++++", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1); 
    }

    public List<DescribeVaultOutput> getVaults()
    {
        var response = this.client.ListVaults();

        List<DescribeVaultOutput> vaultList = response.VaultList;

        return vaultList;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ... it almost seems the documentation is faulty. Most likely it's `protected`, you should be able to see that when you go to it's definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS SDKs for .NET are different depending on the target SDK. For example, Glacier has [3 different targets](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/tree/master/sdk/src/Services/Glacier/Generated):

- _bcl35
- _bcl45
- _netstandard

The .NET 3.5 target doesn't have a `AmazonGlacierClient`, so we can rule that out. You are either targetting a .NET Framework >= 4.5 or some implementation of .NET Standard (probably .NET Core).

The .NET 4.5+ version does have a public [`GetVaults()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/Glacier/Generated/_bcl45/AmazonGlacierClient.cs#L3278) method.
The .NET Standard version only has an internal [`GetVaults()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/Glacier/Generated/_netstandard/AmazonGlacierClient.cs#L2112), but you have a public [`ListVaultsAsync()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/Glacier/Generated/_netstandard/AmazonGlacierClient.cs#L2174) that you can use.

Remember that the SDK for .NET is open source, you can always take a look if the documentation seems wrong like in this case.

Comment: yes, the code says something other than the documentation  ` internal virtual ListVaultsResponse ListVaults()`  Async version fixed this issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Lots of methods are like this.  I was trying to use ListDashboards, but only the Async version ListDashboardsAsync is publicly accessible.